# Как повесить событие на вде одновременно зажатые клавиши клавиатуры?

Tags: javascript

Искал по СОФ подобный вопрос но находил решение только для Питона.
Есть простая задача, выполнить определенное действие при зажатии (именно зажатии!) 2 клавишь.
Пример кода:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
   if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 83) {
   delete_storage();
   }
}
```

Но если я хочу повесить событие на 2 клавиши и не одна из них не является Альтом, Шифтом или Энтером?
Например, клавиши S и D? Тогда код должен выглядеть вот так:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
   if (e.keyCode === 68 && e.keyCode === 83) {
   delete_storage();
   }
}
```

Но он не работает XD. Почему? И как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12444641/6138795  - общий большой ответ. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45955197/6138795 - кратко. В целом - содержать map с нажатыми клавишами и сравнивать что сейчас нажато

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1098203/342397 Только недавно схожий вопрос был, посмотри

Comment: может не работает, потому что 68 != 83 ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function pressKeys(doFunc, ...keys) {
        let clicked = new Set();

        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
            clicked.add(e.code);
            for (let key of keys) {
                if (!clicked.has(key)) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            clicked.clear();
            doFunc();
        });
        document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
            clicked.delete(e.code);
        });

    }
    pressKeys(()=>console.log('Нажаты S и D'),"KeyS", "KeyD");
```